# Dynamic control in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to create a kind of 4 x 3 matrix with textboxes and checkboxes. Whether the element is checkbox or textbox depends upon the values in database.I want it to be dynamic. What is the best way to start?

```
// something like this but I need to fill in each elements of the matrix...
  private void CreateSpecificControl(string requestedType)
        {
                if (requestedType == "CheckBox")
                {

                    CheckBox control1 = new CheckBox();

                    control1.Click += new EventHandler(chk_CheckedChanged);

                   //TableLayout panel
                    layout.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 25));
                    layout.Controls.Add(control1);

                }
                else
                {
                    Label control1 = new Label();

                    control1.Text = "Not a checkbox";
                    layout.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 25));
                    layout.Controls.Add(control1);

                }

        }
```

Comment: Can you please update your question with some more details, like what programming language / environment you are talking about and maybe a bit of context about the particular problem.  Thanks.

Comment: It's in winform and I was using the TableLayoutPanel with growstyle as addrows. But that way I could not pick and choose each element. All the elements will have to be either textbox or checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

Use a usercontrol. See this [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302342.aspx).

At run time you can change the contents of the User control. There's a Controls collection in each user control that you can add or remove elements from. For example if you want to add check boxes just do somethign like this:

```
myUserControl.Controls.Add(new CheckBox());
```

Similarly elements can be removed from this collection, thus achieving a dynamic behaviour.

Comment: What does a user control achieve?